# How to get current item from Spinner without listener - c# android xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, spinner

I am trying to get the item that is currently in the spinner, but not by Selected or OnChange events.

```
 public string GetCurrentSport()
        {

            string currentSport = spnSports.GetItemAtPosition(0).ToString();
            return currentSport;
        }
```

the above code throws and error, I am guessing it is the wrong code to get the Spinner value, this is getting passed to another class from a button click so i can't use the OnSelected Events.

If you need more code, please ask.

Answer (score 1):

A `Spinner` via its subclassed `AdapterView` has three methods to obtain the "item" that is currently selected, `SelectedItem`, `SelectedItemId`, `SelectedItemPosition`:

```
// The data corresponding to the currently selected item, or null if there is nothing selected.
var javaObj = spinner.SelectedItem; // getSelectedItem

//The id corresponding to the currently selected item, or INVALID_ROW_ID if nothing is selected.
var id = spinner.SelectedItemId; // getSelectedItemId

// Return the position of the currently selected item within the adapter's data set
var postion = spinner.SelectedItemPosition; // getSelectedItemPosition
```

re: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem()

Comment: I do that in the OnCreate, I put this code in: `string selected = spnSports.SelectedItemId.ToString()` and it give a `Null Exception Error`

Comment: At Class level:
`Spinner spnSports;`
In Oncreate:
`spnSports = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spnSportCategory);`

Comment: Everything works before that as i am using an adapter to load the spinner values, but it is only giving me null when I run the above code.

Comment: the value, that is what I am saying

Comment: @DEFALT It CAN be `null` if nothing is currently selected: `The data corresponding to the currently selected item, or null if there is nothing selected.`